# ASP.NET: How to set the css class of a Control during DataBind?

Tags: asp.net, css

A table row is generated using an asp:Repeater:

```
<asp:repeater ID="announcementsRepeater" OnItemDataBound="announcementsRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="Server">
   <itemtemplate>
      <tr id="announcementRow" class="announcementItem" runat="server">...</tr>
   </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Now in the data-bind i want to mark "unread" announcements with a different css class, so that the web-guy can perform whatever styling he wants to differentiate between read and unread announcements:

```
protected void announcementsRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
      return;

   // get the associated data item
   Announcement announcement = (Announcement)e.Item.DataItem;

   WebControl row = (WebControl)e.Item.FindControl("announcementRow");
      if (row != null)
         row.CssClass = row.CssClass + " announcementItemUnread";
}
```

except the cast fails at runtime:

```
System.InvalidCastException occurred
  Message="Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl'."
```

It turns out that `HtmlTableRow` has a different parent heirarchy than `WebControl`:

```
HtmlTableRow
   : HtmlContainerControl
      : HtmlControl
         : System.Web.UI.Control
```

which is ultimately where WebControl comes from

```
WebControl
   : System.Web.UI.Control
```

So i changed the code to try to use a System.Web.UI.Control instead:

```
Control row = (Control)e.Item.FindControl("announcementRow");
if (row != null)
   row.CssClass = row.CssClass + " announcementItemUnread";
```

But `Control` doesn't contain a definition for `CssClass`:

```
'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'CssClass'
```

so how do i set the css class name for a `<TR>` element during DataBind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   HtmlControl htmlRow = (HtmlControl)row; 
   htmlRow.Attributes["class"] = htmlRow.Attributes["class"] + " announcementItemUnread";
```

Answer (score 1):

HtmlTableRow htmlRow = (HtmlTableRow)row;
 htmlRow.Attributes.Add("class","announcementItemUnread");

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to HtmlTableRow

```
HtmlTableRow row = (HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("announcementRow");
```

Comment: HtmlTableRow does not contain a CssName property either:

'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow' does not contain a definition for 'CssClass'

Answer (score 0):

Why not just bind in the declaration?

```
<tr id="announcementRow" runat="server" class="<#% functionToDetermineWhichtoShow(ItemInBoundSetToPass) %>">...</tr>
```

Comment: tr element doesn't have a cssClass, only ASP.NET controls do.  In this case you'd need a function to set the class attribute.  Probably easier just to do it in the code-behind.

Comment: Also, i'd rather not hide the css class names that i'll be assigning too much from the web-designer.